# How can limit the search in an adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, autocompletetextview

I have implemented an autocomplete adapter that works fine. I have found the code on this forum.

This adapter lists customers and their associated code :

Cust01  061213
Cust02  086554
oldCust01  654235
...
...
Cust12  876521

At the moment if I search with "12" in the autocomplete it shows :

Cust01  061213
Cust12  876521

And now I would like it to only show the corresponding customer but with its associated code :

Cust12  876521

In other words, I only want the search to be made on the 6 first characters.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: `Is there a way to do that ?` most likely, but you'd have to post your code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and when needed, how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can try to help you with a problem. You're often expected to do your own homework and research before asking a question.